# LMC Instructions for traffic lights (if statements)

Tags: little-man-computer

I have an assignment for school where I have an input number, and based on that input, I take the traffic controller and use different directions.

The LMC knows add, subtraction, input, output, etc. Based on my input (either 0, 5, 10, or 15) I have to do something.

What is the best way to go about working this out within LMC?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would be taking the number away from the input then using the `BRZ` command to figure out what is going on.

The code would look like this:

```
INP
STA A
BRZ LOOP1
LDA A
SUB FIVE
BRZ LOOP2
LDA A
SUB TEN
BRZ LOOP3
BRA LOOP4
LOOP1    *IF INP = 0 THEN DO SOME STUFF*
LOOP2    *IF INP = 5 THEN DO SOME STUFF*
LOOP3    *IF INP = 10 THEN DO SOME STUFF*
LOOP4    *IF INP = 15 THEN DO SOME STUFF*
A DAT
FIVE DAT 5
TEN DAT 10
```

***Note:*** *This code is the best representation of what one would need without further clarification of the question from the OP. Please feel free to comment any problems and I will endeavor to fix them.*